# How to set specific environment variables when activating conda environment?

Tags: anaconda, conda

Does anyone know how to automatically set environment variables when activating an env in conda?
I have tried editing */bin/activate, but that adds the new environment variables for every new env that is created. I want to set env variables that are specific to each env.

Comment: There is a duplicate of this question here which provides some additional detail people may find useful in the future: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46826497/conda-set-ld-library-path-for-env-only

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Use the files `$CONDA_PREFIX/etc/conda/activate.d` and `$CONDA_PREFIX/etc/conda/deactivate.d`, where `$CONDA_PREFIX` is the path to the environment.

See [the section on managing environments in the official documentation](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#macos-and-linux) for reference.

Comment: Thanks! I created the folder $PREFIX/etc/conda/activate.d, put env_vars.sh inside it and specified a some env variables in env_vars.sh. The specified env vars loaded on activation.

Comment: Is there a similar solution for Windows?

Comment: @PythonRunner Thanks, that was it! See [here](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/envs.html#saved-environment-variables) for these instructions.

Comment: for **windows**: check this [link](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#windows)

Comment: how do you find "$PREFIX"? I tried to figure it out by looking at `which python` within the env, but that folder tree has no `etc/`

Comment: @DimaLituiev you may need to create the `etc/conda` directory.

Comment: I have the same question as @DimaLituiev, I have a directory `anaconda3/etc/` but not sure if I should create `conda` under that directory, and if so, how I would specify the environment I want to edit `activate.d` for.

Comment: For posterity, this answer covers the details related to `$PREFIX` very well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46826497/conda-set-ld-library-path-for-env-only

Comment: If you're using PowerShell on Windows, you just need to create `env_vars.ps1` files instead of `env_vars.bat` files, and, within these, set/unset the environment variables accordingly (this is currently omitted from the [documentation](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#windows).

Comment: Is this still valid with the current `conda actvate` instead of `source activate`?

Comment: Since a couple of days (conda 4.9) it's possible to define them in your environment.yml-file. You can find instructions in same link as given in answer.

Answer (score 100):

## Environment Variables as Configuration Settings

Conda v4.8 introduced a new command-line interface in the `conda-env` tool for managing environment variables on a per-environment basis. The command is `conda env config vars` and here is the help description as of v4.8.3 for the command overall:

```
$ conda env config vars -h
usage: conda-env config vars [-h] {list,set,unset} ...

Interact with environment variables associated with Conda environments

Options:

positional arguments:
  {list,set,unset}
    list            List environment variables for a conda environment
    set             Set environment variables for a conda environment
    unset           Unset environment variables for a conda environment

optional arguments:
  -h, --help        Show this help message and exit.

examples:
    conda env config vars list -n my_env
    conda env config vars set MY_VAR=something OTHER_THING=ohhhhya
    conda env config vars unset MY_VAR
```

Perhaps a bit verbose, but it avoids having to manually manage files in `etc/conda/(de|)activate.d`.

### YAML Specification

Added in Conda v4.9, there is now support for automatic defining of environment-specific variables as part of an environment YAML definition. For example,

```
name: foo
channels:
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - python
variables:
  MY_VAR: something
  OTHER_VAR: ohhhhya
```

which would set up the environment variables `MY_VAR` and `OTHER_VAR` to be set and unset on environment activation and deactivation, respectively.

Comment: This is the most up-to-date answer; the accepted answer should be this one. I personally think the YAML specification is the best way to go, as you can commit it to version control.

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#setting-environment-variables) has more details on setting environment variables in this manner.

Comment: If the variable that I am defining is PATH, for example, how can I append to it instead of just overwriting it?

Comment: [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73721599/in-the-conda-environment-yml-file-how-do-i-append-to-existing-variables-without) the question related to my previous comment.

Answer (score 13):

The accepted answer (`conda/activate.d` and `conda/deactivate.d`) works well enough, but it is inconvenient if you want the environment variables to be version controlled without putting the *entire* environment into version control too. Generally you'd want to store only the `environment.yml` file in version control.

(I understand that this does not apply to all projects - sometimes the entire reason for using environment variables is to *prevent* that particular configuration getting stored in version control.)

My preference (on Windows, but the same principle would apply on Linux) is to create a (version-controlled) `activate.cmd` file in the root of the project directory that sets the environemnt variable(s) and then calls conda's own activate.bat script.

Example (a per-project pylint configuration):

```
set PYLINTRC=%cd%\pylintrc
@activate.bat %cd%\env
```

Note that on Windows at least you have to set the environment variables *before* calling `activate.bat` because the call to `activate.bat` never returns to the calling batch file. You also have to name your own script something other than `activate.bat` to avoid recursion, which is why I chose the `cmd` extension (which is treated by Windows as a batch file in this context).

Answer (score 2):

So for virtualenv on Ubuntu I did the below where my virtual environement names is my_env and my environmental variables I want to persist were VAR_A and VAR_B:

```
virtualenv my_env
vim my_env/bin/activate
```

This opens the file and you can append your env variables to the end of the file like the below:

```
# This is me env variables to persist
export VAR_A=/home/developer/my_workspace/var_a
export VAR_B=/home/developer/my_workspace/var_b
```

Then exit the file.

Activate your virtualenv with

```
source my_env/bin/activate
```

Then your env variables should be good. Can verify like the below:

```
printenv | grep VAR_
VAR_B=/home/developer/my_workspace/var_b
VAR_A=/home/developer/my_workspace/var_a
```

Comment: But what about unsetting the variables when deactivating?