# How to associate a conda enviroment with a project directory

Tags: anaconda, virtualenv, miniconda

I have been using miniconda for a while and have set up conda environments for each for each of my projects. What I can't figure out after looking through the documentation, is there a way to bond/associate my conda environment to my project folder for that conda environment? So that when I activate a specific conda environment it moves directly into the associated project directory. This virtualenvwrapper etc. can do for example. Is conda able to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [Activating an environment](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#activating-an-environment), conda automatically executes "activation scripts" when an environment is activated. These scripts are typically provided by conda packages installed in the environment.

Just add a script of your own with a `cd` command. See here for details:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43415167/11451509

Comment: Thanks, that was what I was looking for.