# Id like to run a sh script just after conda active

Tags: linux, conda

hello i need to run a list of **commands** every time right after i activate a conda enviroment

`conda activate my_env`

**i changed** this files and other ones

> .bashrc
>
> conda.sh
>
> .profile

but i canut run this command automatically every time i start my conda env

```
source /home/user/setup.sh
```

some one can help me ? I looked into conda manuals but i didint find anything

Comment: does that help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34606196/create-a-post-activate-script-in-conda

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create a post activate script in Conda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34606196/create-a-post-activate-script-in-conda)