# Conda uses .local packages

Tags: pycharm, anaconda, conda

I feel like this is a basic question, so feel free to direct me to any resources:

My conda environment uses .local ahead of the package version specified in the yaml file for any package that exists in local. How do I get it to ignore .local, if that's possible?

I'm using PyCharm and Ubuntu.

If I can provide more information, let me know.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think all python interpreters will use packages from `site.USER_SITE` before any others, and by default that location is `~/.local/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages`.  That's because `site.USER_BASE` defaults to `~/.local`.

But fortunately, you can override `site.USER_BASE` to some other value with an environment variable: `PYTHONUSERBASE`.  Since you want to disable it entirely, you should supply a non-empty nonsense value.  For example:

```sh
$ export PYTHONUSERBASE=intentionally-disabled
$ python -c "import site; print(site.USER_SITE)"
intentionally-disabled/lib/python3.7/site-packages
```

Docs:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html#site.USER_BASE
- https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONUSERBASE

To make sure that variable is set every time you're using that conda environment, you can create a post-activation shell script in `${CONDA_PREFIX}/etc/conda/activate.d/`, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34606196/162094).

```
cat > ${CONDA_PREFIX}/etc/conda/activate.d/disable-PYTHONUSERBASE.sh << EOF
#!/bin/bash
export PYTHONUSERBASE=intentionally-disabled
EOF

chmod +x ${CONDA_PREFIX}/etc/conda/activate.d/disable-PYTHONUSERBASE.sh
```

But frankly, I think the simplest option is to never use `~/.local` for python packages.  Just move or delete them.  It causes issues like this.  I've only encountered it when its causing  problems -- I've never seen anyone actually benefit from using that Python feature.  I wish they would just disable it by default.

---

**Edit:** If your IDE allows you to specify the flags that are passed to python itself, then you can use [the `python -s` option](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34606196/162094).

Comment: thanks for the great answer! i implemented your solution but also needed to add PYTHONUSERBASE as a user defined environment variable in my PyCharm run configurations because they didn't have PYTHONUSERBASE even though the terminal for the conda environment did. you don't recommend deleting `~/.local`, right? just deleting the packages installed in it. i imagine deleting the folder might cause problems.

Comment: Hmm, yeah, I guess that's best.  I don't really know what `~/.local` is for, TBH.  [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14535/whats-the-local-folder-for-in-my-home-directory) claims that it's for more than just Python.

Comment: I guess the cleaner solution is to set `PYTHONNOUSERSITE` (see <https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONNOUSERSITE>), which has the same effect as `python -s` (<https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html#site.ENABLE_USER_SITE>), instead of setting `PYTHONUSERBASE` to some nonsense value.