# Possible to prune unwanted packages using environment.yml file when building conda environment?

Tags: python, pip, conda

I am making a conda virtual environment using an `environment.yml` file. In my package I want to use opencv version 4.1, from conda-forge. It installs great using the following line in the yml file:

```
- conda-forge::opencv=4.1
```

Unfortunately another package I'm including as a dependency has `opencv-python` as a dependency. Hence, once the environment is resolved, you end up with both `opencv` (version 4.1) and `opencv-python` (version 4.5) installed. This leads to problems when running my code.

Luckily, when I manually uninstall `opencv-python` everything works just fine in my package.

The problem is I don't want my github repo install instructions to be like: "Create this virtual environment with `environment.yml` file. Oh BTW you then need to enter `pip uninstall opencv-python` or else you will run into problems."

Is there a way to take care of this last pruning step in my `environment.yml` file, so things will just work out of the box?

Comment: Looks like there is not yet any official support in conda for this feature.  Here's the issue to track: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/6805

Comment: @StuartBerg thanks this is super helpful. Following. Seems it will be a really helpful feature for these kinds of corner cases.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you could create your own conda package, which will be mostly empty except for a special [activation script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43415167/162094) in `${PREFIX}/etc/conda/activate.d/`.  The activation script will check if `opencv-python` is installed, and remove it.

This recipe would do it:

```
recipe/
├── meta.yaml
└── uninstall-opencv-python.sh
```

```yaml
# meta.yaml
package:
  name: my-hack-to-uninstall-opencv-python
  version: 0.1

build:
  number: 0
  noarch: generic
  script:
   - mkdir -p {{ PREFIX }}/etc/conda/activate.d/
   - cp {{ RECIPE_DIR }}/uninstall-opencv-python.sh {{ PREFIX }}/etc/conda/activate.d/
```

```sh
# uninstall-opencv-python.sh
if (pip list | grep opencv-python > /dev/null); then
   echo "Uninstalling opencv-python"
   pip uninstall opencv-python
fi
```

Build that recipe and upload the resulting package to your own channel on `anaconda.org`.  Then, add a line to your `environment.yml` file:

```yaml
- mychannel::my-hack-to-uninstall-opencv-python
```

The only downside is that it will run that script *every time* the environment is activated.  But it's a relatively fast script, so maybe that's not a problem.  Obviously any solution to this particular problem will be somewhat of a hack, no matter what you come up with.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't want my github repo install instructions to be like ... "Oh BTW you then need to enter `pip uninstall opencv-python`..."

Well, what about the following commands instead?

```sh
# This extra line is necessary if running within a script,
# otherwise 'conda activate' is broken.
# https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/7980#issuecomment-441358406
source $(conda info --base)/etc/profile.d/conda.sh

conda create -n foo conda-dependencies.yml
conda activate foo
pip install --no-deps pypi-dependencies.txt
```

That's more than one command, but at least it doesn't involve an `uninstall` step.

---

To produce those two files for your users, run:

```
conda env export -f conda-dependencies.yml
```

...then remove the `pypi` dependencies from that file and copy them into `pypi-dependencies.txt` (with the appropriate syntax changes, of course).  But delete the `opencv-python` line.

Comment: I really like this suggestion it is pretty simple, and I think I could incorporate it into a single shell script. Will test it tonight.  I'm also wondering if just having them enter the uninstall manually might be not all that bad, but this is more elegant.

Comment: It just occurred to me that (1) I forgot the `activate` step, and (2) you can't call `conda activate` within a script unless you run a special line in advance.  See my edits above.