# Set include-path for header only library installed with conda

Tags: c++, conda, include-path, xtensor

I was recently advised to check out conda as a package manager. Unfortunately I don't succeed in finding how to make my compiler find a header-only library installed with conda? Ideally I would like to not having to manually specify a path to my compiler at all.

(The context is that I come from homebrew on macOS, which creates symbolic links on the right locations. Obviously this is what conda avoids. But still, a simple way to compile simple examples would be nice!)

---

#### Example

For example, if my code is the one below. *Note: this question is meant to be generic, not related to a specific package, nor do I want to have to manually specify again my specific virtual environment.*

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <xtensor/xarray.hpp>
#include <xtensor/xio.hpp>

int main()
{
  xt::xarray<double> a
    {{1.0, 2.0, 3.0},
     {2.0, 5.0, 7.0},
     {2.0, 5.0, 7.0}};

  std::cout << a;
}
```

I have 'installed' the library using

```bash
conda create --name example
source activate example
conda install -c conda-forge xtensor-python
```

**Now I would like to compile just with**

```bash
clang++ -std=c++14 test.cpp
```

Note that I know that this works:

```bash
clang++ -std=c++14 -I~/miniconda3/envs/example/include test.cpp
```

But I don't think that this is wanted, because:

- The path includes the environment (`example`).
- It is system dependent.

Comment: If there is a system environment variable that sets include paths, you can set that when the environment is activated

Comment: @darthbith Thanks for your reply. I guess a big deficiency is that there is no such environment variable. I could, of course, introduce my own environment variable, say `${INCLUDEPATH}`. If I were to do that, how can I set it based on the virtual environment?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46833531/2449192

Comment: @darthbith Nice, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least on unix systems, a solution would be to use

```
clang++ -std=c++14 -I"${CONDA_PREFIX}"/include test.cpp
```

thereby `"${CONDA_PREFIX}"` point to the root of the current conda environment. In this case:

```
~/miniconda3/envs/example
```

Answer (score 2):

I would rather export [CPATH or CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/clang.html#envvar-C_INCLUDE_PATH,OBJC_INCLUDE_PATH,CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH,OBJCPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH) variable to add ${CONDA_PREFIX}/include : it would untangle compilation process (compiling test.cpp) from conda environment allowing portability of your compilation process.

> CPATH
> If this environment variable is present, it is treated as a delimited list of paths to be added to the default system include path list. The delimiter is the platform dependent delimiter, as used in the PATH environment variable.

> C_INCLUDE_PATH, OBJC_INCLUDE_PATH, CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH, OBJCPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH
> These environment variables specify additional paths, as for CPATH, which are only used when processing the appropriate language.

Use https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html?highlight=env#setting-environment-variables to set environment variables.

```
$ conda env config vars set CPATH=${CONDA_PREFIX}/include:${CPATH}
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.