# set environmental variables in a certain conda environment based on linux

Tags: python, linux, installation, conda

For install one software, I create a new virtual environment(called **envirpy36**) by conda since its installation a bit complex for me.

I did as the document in **envirpy36**

```
python setup.py develop
```

> "Then I recommend setting the following environmental variables"

```
  export BASENJIDIR=~/code/Basenji
  export PATH=$BASENJIDIR/bin:$PATH
  export PYTHONPATH=$BASENJIDIR/bin:$PYTHONPATH
```

For the linux system without conda environment, I know it means add them to my `home/userme/.bashrc` file.

But for now I'm in **envirpy36**, I'm not sure what "set the following environmental variables" means, at least, I think this "process" shouldn't affect all conda environments, it will just for **envirpy36**.

Actually, I have no idea here and search around.
I know it's for this software installation part, but I guess it is a case and the core problem is general maybe.

Thanks in advance for any view!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conda set LD\_LIBRARY\_PATH for env only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46826497/conda-set-ld-library-path-for-env-only)

Comment: Thanks! It's what i'm seeking! But still a part confused me, should edit ./etc/conda/deactivate.d/env_vars.sh as follows?
```
#!/bin/sh
`unset BASENJIDIR=~/code/Basenji`  
`unset PATH=$BASENJIDIR/bin:$PATH`  
`unset PYTHONPATH=$BASENJIDIR/bin:$PYTHONPATH`

Since contains about dir and path, not key and file, in addition, for linux .bashrc no unset step, so I'm not sure here. @darthbith

Comment: The other answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49238956/2449192 should give you a  way to reset everything.

Comment: Thanks！I think there maybe other way to realize, but a little dangerous and rude. In the certain environment，`which python` then can get the python path of this conda environment, but it is not a just a python place, also can put **files under export PATH bin**into this place, of course, after some checks like file name conflict and so on. However, i'm not ensure about this way.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure what your question is. Can you try to rephrase it?

Comment: Sure. Another way(take risk in a degree and simple) to achive same purpose. 
In this certain conda environment: 
`which python`(we must already have python in this environment), we will get a path call **pathx** here;
put(link or copy) files into **$PATH_export/bin**;
then, take place of creativing env_vars.sh but realize “variables for env only”.