# Linking FFTW library installed with Conda to gfortran?

Tags: fortran, conda, gfortran, fftw

I am trying to build a environment.yml file to make gathering all the dependencies for a project that is written in Python, C, and Fortran easier. One of the dependencies for the Fortran part of the code is the [FFTW library](http://www.fftw.org/), specifically the **fftw3f** portion of the library (single precision float, version 3+?). I have tried to install it through several different channels on Anaconda cloud, specifically [the Omnia channel](https://anaconda.org/omnia/fftw3f) and [conda-forge](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/fftw). However when I try to link the library with gfortran like `gfortran -o output_name input_names -lfftw3f`, I receive the following error I am not sure how to fix:

> /opt/anaconda3/envs/env_name/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -lfftw3f collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I do no believe this file path is even valid, but I know the library is being installed because I can view it with `conda list`. However I am completely stuck with how to approach this problem. I believe there is a mismatch with where conda is installing the package and where gfortran thinks it is? Or perhaps I am not installing the right package?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The linker doesn't know by default how to find libraries that are in your Conda env. A nice trick is to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to include the active env's `/lib` dir whenever you activate the env, as suggested in this possible duplicate of [Conda set LD\_LIBRARY\_PATH for env only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46826497/conda-set-ld-library-path-for-env-only).