# Env $PATH has not the correct value after conda deactivate

Tags: python, linux, conda

I use a conda environment with a lot of dependencies and some personal packages compiled with conda-build.
When doing `conda activate iota2_dev` I'll update the `$PATH` variable to propose some executable to the user.
The `activate.sh` script is available [here](https://framagit.org/iota2-project/iota2/-/blob/develop/install/recipes/iota2/scripts/activate.sh)

After doing conda deactivate the following `/home/btardy/miniconda3/envs/iota2_dev/bin` is still in `$PATH`.

However the following added in activate.sh `${CONDA_PREFIX}/lib/python3.6/site-packages/iota2:${CONDA_PREFIX}/lib/python3.6/site-packages/iota2/Common/Tools:` is well removed after conda deactivate

After looking at all activate scripts in `/home/btardy/miniconda3/envs/iota2_dev/etc/conda/activate.d` no one update `$PATH` variable.
It seems that when entering in the first activate.sh script `$PATH` was already modified with `/home/btardy/miniconda3/envs/iota2_dev/bin`... then it seems that our activate/deactivate procedure works well.

The question is why and how the `$PATH` is modified before, and why it is not reset at the end.

If I comment the `$PATH` modification in our `activate.sh`, the path is correctly cleared after conda deactivate. But we loose simple access to executables.

What happened:

```
~$ echo $PATH
/home/btardy/miniconda3/condabin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
~$ conda activate iota2_dev
(iota2) ~$ echo $PATH
/home/btardy/miniconda3/envs/iota2_dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/iota2:/home/btardy/miniconda3/envs/iota2_dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/iota2/Common/Tools:/home/btardy/miniconda3/envs/iota2_dev/bin:/home/btardy/miniconda3/condabin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
(iota2) ~$ conda deactivate
~$ echo $PATH
/home/btardy/miniconda3/envs/iota2_dev/bin:/home/btardy/miniconda3/condabin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

What should happened:

```
~$ echo $PATH
/home/btardy/miniconda3/condabin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
~$ conda activate iota2
(iota2) ~$ echo $PATH
/home/btardy/miniconda3/envs/iota2_dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/iota2:/home/btardy/miniconda3/envs/iota2_dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/iota2/Common/Tools:/home/btardy/miniconda3/envs/iota2_dev/bin:/home/btardy/miniconda3/condabin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
(iota2) ~$ conda deactivate
~$ echo $PATH
/home/btardy/miniconda3/condabin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

With an environment containing other packages (no $PATH modification in activate.sh) the path is correctly cleared after conda deactivate.
I did not found how conda natively store and restore $PATH. There is a variable somewhere that we can use in our scripts to restore correctly the path ?

Any help or explanations about the behaviour of conda activate when no activate.sh script are available will be also useful.

This question is also on [conda github](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/11021) )

Comment: It sounds like you are modifying the activate script directly or something of the likes? Have you tried simply creating a custom script in activate.d and deactivate.d as laied out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49238956/5012099)?

Comment: Yes exactly. We store the $PATH content when entering in the activate script. The issue here is it was already modified by conda. And I don't find where conda update the path and store the initial $PATH value... I have just added a custom script "activate.sh" in activate.d and the PATH is already modified too. The issue seems very linked only with PATH as we also modify LD_LIBRARY_PATH and it works correctly for it.

Answer (score 1):

I took a quick look. It seems like `conda` does its own modification of `PATH` before calling anything in activate.d, but also before calling anything in deactivate.d, so when you have in `activate.d\test.sh` something like

```
echo ${PATH}
export OLD_PATH=${PATH}

export PATH=/usr/users/dummy/testdir:${PATH}
```

you will have in `OLD_PATH` already the `bin` directory of your environment. So when you then do in `deactivate.d\test.sh` something like

```
export PATH=${OLD_PATH}
```

Then you will add the `bin` directory to `PATH` after conda has purged it. Only way to directly adress your question that I can think of is to prune the already added prefix to `PATH` in your `activate.d` script like this:

```
export OLD_PATH=$(echo ${PATH} | sed 's/^[^:]*://g')
```

**BUT**

I personally do not like that solution much. You are relying on the fact that conda will just prepend one entry to PATH which might or might not be a stable assumption. I am not an expert in conda recipes, but I am fairly certain that it should not be too difficult to just copy scripts into the actual `bin` directory of the env (which is added to PATH automatically) and have them as entry points for your code.

Comment: Thank you for your answers @FlyingTeller. I agree that pruning the `$PATH` is not an elegant solution. I create alias for the entry points instead of modify `$PATH`, and then unalias them in deactivate.sh. Another solution is to warn user to close the terminal once they deactivate the environment to avoid conflict in `$PATH`