# Conda: specify environment variable before creating env from YAML file

Tags: python, conda

I am creating a `environment.yml` file for the creation of a custom environment.

One of the package (which I install via `pip`) requires an environment variable to be set (namely `MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.7` in order to make `gcc` happy).

How can I do that?

```
name: mypy27
channels:
  # Default distribution from Continuum/Anaconda
  - defaults
  # Conda forge distribution
  # https://conda-forge.org
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - python=2.7
  - anaconda
  - pip:
    - rootnumpy
    - git+https://mypackage.git#egg=mypackage
```

The key is to set the environment variable before `rootnumpy` installation is started.

Comment: Why don't you set the environment variable by yourself? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501678/set-environment-variables-on-mac-os-x-lion

Comment: @PedroLobito I could off course but I would prefer if it is self contained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Conda v4.9, you can define environment variables in your 'environment.yml' file:

```
name: foo
channels:
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - python
variables:
  MY_VAR: something
  OTHER_VAR: ohhhhya
```

See [the documentation](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#setting-environment-variables) or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62508395/4341436) for more information.