# Activate conda environment in cron (including environment variables!)

Tags: python, cron, anaconda, virtualenv, conda

I struggle with running **fully** activated conda environment from withing cron.

My current solution is calling a specific python interpreter directly  with the absolute path, as suggested in [many](https://hackersandslackers.com/code-snippet-corner-getting-conda-envs-and-environment-variables-to-play-nicely-with-cron/), [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31598963/how-to-set-specific-environment-variables-when-activating-conda-environment) posts before. So my current solution looks like this:

```
# crontab file

* * * * * /home/user/miniconda2/envs/env_xyz/bin/python my_script.py
```

This works in terms of finding correct python libraries, but it turns out that cron's shell misses some of the virtual-environment-specific environment variables, that get normally loaded in shell's scope with a standard `source activate env_xyz`.

Authors of the above links provide a solution based on the [official conda docs](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#saving-environment-variables), but this solution seems to be designed for sharing manually added variables, not the ones that get added automatically by installing python dependecies (in my case gdal's `GDAL_DATA`).

I also tried adding a `SHELL=/bin/bash` at the beginning of cron file  and using many possible shebang/SHELL combinations, all with the same result...

~

Does anybody know how to achieve a behaviour that would allow me calling `source activate env_xyz` either from cronfile directly, or eventually from within a bash script wrapper, that would then be called by cron?

I would like a portable solution, that would only require versioning of my `environment.yml` file, not environment variables as well.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcron%5D+%5Bvirtualenv%5D+activate

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50556692/7976758