# How to fix Conda "missing path to environment variable"?

Tags: python, ubuntu-16.04, conda

I have a conda environment named `tensorflow_p36`. When I run `import mujoco-py` I get the following error:

> Exception:  Missing path to your environment variable.
>
> Please add following line to .bashrc:
>        export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/ubuntu/.mujoco/mujoco200/bin

Therefore, I add the line above to .bashrc:

```
(tensorflow_p36) ubuntu@ip-172-XX-XX-XXX:~$ echo 'export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/ubuntu/.mujoco/mujoco200/bin' >> ~/.bashrc
```

and

```
(tensorflow_p36) ubuntu@ip-172-XX-XX-XXX:~$ source ~/.bashrc
```

This however does not add the environment variable to the conda environmnet. Such that when I run

```
ubuntu@ip-172-XX-XX-XXX:~$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

I get:

> :/home/ubuntu/.mujoco/mujoco200/bin

but when I run from inside the virtual env

```
(tensorflow_p36) ubuntu@ip-172-XX-XX-XXX:~$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

I don't get the exported path showing. Any suggestions on how I can fix this?

Comment: The essence of what you need to do is in: [How to set specific environment variables when activating conda environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31598963/how-to-set-specific-environment-variables-when-activating-conda-environment). Basically, make the change to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` as part of activation instead of globally.