# How to add my own Module to my Anaconda environment

Tags: python, module, anaconda, virtualenv, python-import

Basically the question is already up there. I created my environemt for the project with miniconda. Now I want to include some modules, bundled in directory into this environemt. So what I did was putting the directory in the '''/miniconda/env/..../sitepackages/mymodule/''' directory. When I run the module from the command line, where my current working directory is this directory it works. As soon as I just activate this conda environment and work in a different directory it tells me `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'stdiio'`

Hope it kind of makes sense and got more or less clear the question. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

If your module is installable (e.g., you have a `setup.py`), then you can activate your Conda env and install using pip:

```
conda activate -n myenv
pip install /some/path/to/mymodule
```

If you are actively developing the module, then use `pip install -e`, instead.

If your module is not installable, but just some source folders with `__init__.py` files, then another option is to add the containing folder to `PYTHONPATH`. For example, if your module is in `/some/path/to/mymodule`, then you would use

```
export PYTHONPATH="/some/path/to:$PYTHONPATH"
```

Be careful with `PYTHONPATH` - one can encounter confusing problems if you allow conflicting outside modules to "leak" into your Conda environment (e.g., adding a `site-packages` from another Python install).

Installation should be the preferred option, and if you need to use `PYTHONPATH`, [set it in an env-specific manner using activation hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31598963/how-to-set-specific-environment-variables-when-activating-conda-environment).

Comment: Thanks so much!! Really helped clearing things up!
What if I just copied the folder with a lot of .py (no __init__.py though) -files into the site-packes folder of my conda-environment? 
Could I still import the .py-modules from there into another module when I work with this specific conda environment?

Comment: @RobinKohrs I think you need to have the `__init__.py` for it to be recognized as a module.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll give it a try;)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Python on **Windows**, then it may be best to resolve this by adding **`PYTHONPATH`** to the system variables, or if it's already set, then you may want to append the folder path to the variable.

[image: Picture]

If you don't already know how to access the system variables, or are confused on how to adjust **`PYTHONPATH`** for your needs, then you can check out this StackOverflow question, which has several in-depth answers that explain how to set/update PYTHONPATH on Windows:
[How to add to the PYTHONPATH in Windows, so it finds my modules/packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-so-it-finds-my-modules-packages)