# How to set default conda environment so that whenever I open terminal it should get activated instead of base?

Tags: python, anaconda, environment

I am using Ubuntu 19.10 and I have installed anaconda. Whenever I open terminal the **base** environment gets activated by default. I have another environment called **kf** which I actually use so every time I open terminal I have to *conda activate kf*. Is there a way so that I can set conda to activate **kf** environment by default when I open terminal?

Answer (score 7):

Conda doesn't have a way to set this, AFAIK, but you can easily accomplish it with some editing of `.bashrc` (or whatever the initialization file is for your shell). Simply add

```
conda activate kf
```

to the bottom of your `.bashrc` (e.g., `echo "conda activate kf" >> ~/.bashrc`). Also, you might as well disable the auto-activation of base:

```
conda config --set auto_activate_base false
```

Comment: This solved my problem. The solution is so simple that now I feel dumb for spending two hours searching how to do this.

Comment: Is this file C:\Users\username\.anaconda\navigator\defaults\defaults-2.0.0.ini? C:\Users\username\.anaconda\navigator\anaconda-navigator.ini? How do you find this file for Windows 10 default user installation?

Answer (score 0):

Put your conda env name in file like: `.conda-env in root of your project

Edit your  ~/.bashrc or  ~/.zshrc :

```
# auto activate conda env
FILE=./.conda-env
if [[ -f "$FILE" ]]; then
    CONDA_ENV=$(<$FILE)
    conda activate $CONDA_ENV
fi
```

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31615307/5340217) from [@asmeurer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/161801/asmeurer). It's especially useful if you want all the users enter the same env when a new terminal is initiated.

1. find the anaconda location using `which conda`, e.g. `/usr/local/anaconda3`;
2. `mkdir -p /usr/local/anaconda3/etc/conda/activate.d`;
3. put a file named `default_env.sh` in this folder. the filename is irrelevant; the content of the file is a one-liner: `conda activate kf`.

Comment: This is a wild answer. It is basically recommending that anytime the **base** environment is activating that it immediately activates a different environment. I would not recommend this. Conda may need to actually activate the **base** environment to function properly in some circumstances, and this would cryptically prevent that.