# Cannot load `swrast` and `iris` drivers in Fedora 35

Tags: python, conda, driver, fedora

Essentially, trying to write the following code results in the error below:

##### Code

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3,2,1])
plt.show()
```

##### Error

```
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open iris: /home/xxx/.conda/envs/stat/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/_libs/window/../../../../../libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found (required by /usr/lib64/dri/iris_dri.so) (search paths /usr/lib64/dri, suffix _dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: iris
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open swrast: /home/xxx/.conda/envs/stat/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/_libs/window/../../../../../libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found (required by /usr/lib64/dri/swrast_dri.so) (search paths /usr/lib64/dri, suffix _dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

I found similar errors on StackOverflow but none were what is needed here.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Short answer: `export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6`

Long answer:

The underlying problem is that we have a piece of software that was built with an older C++ compiler. Part of the compiler is its implementation of `libstdc++` which becomes part of the runtime requirements for anything built by the compiler. The software in question has, evidently, brought its own, older implementation of `libstdc++` along for the ride, *and* given its `libstdc++` precedence over the system's `libstdc++`. Typically, this is done via the `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable. Unfortunately, `/usr/lib64/dri/swrast_dri.so` is a piece of system software built by the native compiler for that system, and it's more recent than the compiler that built the other software in question. The result of this is that the older compiler's `libstdc++` gets loaded first, with its older, more limited symbol set. When it then wants to load `swrast`, this fails because `swrast` insists on having the level of compiler/runtime with which it was built. The solution to this whole mess is the force the system's (newer) `libstdc++` into use and prevent the older `libstdc++` from being brought into play. This is achieved via the code snippet `export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6` where we set the preload environment variable.

Comment: This sounds like it circumvents the actual underlying issue. It sounds more like something is wrong with the conda installation and/or paths that should point to conda directories

Comment: @FlyingTeller, if you have suggestions, please feel free to answer the question. Otherwise, this was the best solution I could find comparing to the outrageous ones that others were suggesting online.

Comment: This did not work for me. I did `export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6` and am still seeing the error `libGL error: failed to load driver: iris`

Comment: this is a nice description, but i agree with @adam.  I did the suggested `bashrc` adjustment, but saw no change in behaviour.  I assume this i because i'm not running python through my shell terminal, but rather through a terminal in an IDE (pycharm in my case). The condaforge solution seemed to suppress the errors, but to this point, still having trouble plotting.

Answer (score 49):

The solution proposed by Mahyar Mirrashed is working for me.
On my system (Ubuntu 22.04) the libstdc++.so.6 file is located in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
To know where to find this file I suggest to run the following command :

```
find / -name libstdc++.so.6 2>/dev/null
```

which resulted with files from miniconda, snap and /usr/lib/...
I added the export LD_PRELOAD to my .bashrc file and it's working fine.

```
export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me. I am running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

Comment: Thank you. This worked for me on Linux Mint 21, intel driver with a similar problem.

Comment: Thanks, it works on mine. As additions, we can also set environment variable when starting conda environment, so we don't need set it manually every time: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62508395/1219992

Comment: This did not work for me. I did export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 and am still seeing the error libGL error: failed to load driver: iris

Comment: @Adam did the first line that I suggested give you this exact path?

Comment: @KevinMarchais what ended up working for me was running `conda install -c conda-forge libffi`.

Comment: @Manu : you just made WinUAE (Amiga Emulator) works again on my old Macbook 2008 with Intel driver (Linux Mint 23). Thank you for your short comment, it really helped!

Answer (score 32):

Installing `libstdcxx-ng` from conda-forge should solve this problem.

Command:

```sh
conda install -c conda-forge libstdcxx-ng
```

Comment: This is probably a good solution and has worked for me some times before. I feel like this might be something that should be reported to the `matplotlib` team to ensure that this is listed in the `requirements.txt` for Fedora 35. It would be really annoying to have to run that command every time in every new environment you install `matplotlib` to.

Comment: @MahyarMirrashed I agree, but I am not sure how to approach the reporting. Because, as I understand, anaconda packages various projects by itself.

Comment: This solved the problem for me. I was having trouble installing vtk in Ubuntu 22.04 inside of a new conda environment.

Comment: This worked for me without having to try anything else.

Comment: Works like a charm!! (tested on kali 2023.1). This solution is quite portable as the dependency can be added to the conda environment. Thus, it will work on my colleges' machines as well.

Comment: Amazing answer ! This worked for me in fixing driver-ralated VTK seg-faults on Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was:

```
conda install -c conda-forge libffi
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).