# Kivy not working, MESA-LOADER: failed to open iris and swrast

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, kivy, hybrid-mobile-app

I have installed Kivy 2.1 on Ubuntu 21.10 for my python 3.17.
Am testing the library with a simple and having some errors, it cannot find iris and swrast library, please see code and error below and advise. Thanks

Code:

```
"""
This is Mobile App designed to send email using Kivy lib.
"""

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

Builder.load_file("interface.kv")

class LoginScreen(Screen):
    pass

class RootWidget(ScreenManager):
    pass

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return RootWidget()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

Error after running: python main.py

````
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/fredbitenyo/.kivy/logs/kivy_22-02-25_11.txt [INFO   ] [Kivy      ] v2.1.0rc1 [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/home/fredbitenyo/Downloads/udemy/github_codes/kivy_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/__init__.py" [INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 22:11:17)  [GCC
7.3.0] [INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "/home/fredbitenyo/Downloads/udemy/github_codes/kivy_env/bin/python" [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge log fired. Processing... [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge finished! [INFO   ] [Factory     ] 189 symbols loaded [INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored) [INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2 libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open iris: /usr/lib/dri/iris_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix
_dri) libGL error: failed to load driver: iris libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open swrast: /home/fredbitenyo/anaconda3/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found (required by /usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so) (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix
_dri) libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)   Major opcode of failed request:  149 (GLX)   Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext)   Value in failed request:  0x0   Serial number of failed request:  100   Current serial number in output stream:  101```
````

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: My specific problem is: when I run the code above it raises an exception I have mentioned above => failed to load driver: iris libGL error and swrast X error. I have installed the latest Kivy library and dependencies and still not resolving this problem. Hope I have explain my problem clearly, please assist.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot load \`swrast\` and \`iris\` drivers in Fedora 35](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71010343/cannot-load-swrast-and-iris-drivers-in-fedora-35)

Answer (score 4):

fix the problem,i just removed the symbolic link /home/fredbitenyo/anaconda3/lib/libstdc++.so.6 -> libstdc++.so.6.0.25 that was creating the conflict since it was pointing to a lower version.

Comment: your solution is not clear can you please elaborate because it seems that it is has a relation, coz those errors come s after updating