# libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open iris

Tags: python, linux

when executing a python script, I get this after generating a figure:

libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open iris: /usr/lib/dri/iris_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri) libGL error: failed to load driver: iris libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open iris: /usr/lib/dri/iris_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri) libGL error: failed to load driver: iris libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open swrast: /usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri) libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast

I dont know how to fix it, i have searched for information but have found nothing to help me

Comment: I just searched just for the error message "libGL error: MESA-LOADER" and found something... Please, as a new user here, take the [tour] and read [ask]. Also, extract a [mcve] from your code that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot load \`swrast\` and \`iris\` drivers in Fedora 35](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71010343/cannot-load-swrast-and-iris-drivers-in-fedora-35)

Answer (score 46):

Here are two possible solutions. Try them both and see what works.

### Solution 1

Follow the instructions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72200748/13809128).

### Solution 2

If you are using Anaconda to run this Python script, Anaconda may be the reason. This solution was taken from [here](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/libgl-error-mesa-loader/69746) (update 3), which in turn was taken from [here](https://programmersought.com/article/82837518484/).

From the latter link:

> According to online information, there is a problem with the libstdc++.so file in Anaconda (I use this commercial python distribution). It cannot be associated with the driver of the system, so we removed it and used the libstdc++ that comes with Linux. so creates a soft link there.

To solve this problem, run this in bash:

```
$ cd /home/$USER/miniconda/lib
$ mkdir backup  # Create a new folder to keep the original libstdc++
$ mv libstd* backup  # Put all libstdc++ files into the folder, including soft links
$ cp /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6  ./ # Copy the c++ dynamic link library of the system here
$ ln -s libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so
$ ln -s libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.0.19
```

where `$USER` should be your own username.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Solution 2 worked for me for an anaconda 3 installation in Ubuntu 22.04. Since I wanted to apply it to a _specific_ conda env, `$ENV`, the first command was modified to: ` $ cd /home/$USER/anaconda3/envs/$ENV/lib `

Comment: @programmer I was facing the same problem after updating to ubuntu 22.04. The solution worked for me.

Comment: Solution 2 worked for me. Thanks also @programmer for the specific env option

Comment: Installing libstdcxx-ng from conda-forge should solve this problem.

Command:

conda install -c conda-forge libstdcxx-ng

Answer (score 26):

i resolved this issue with spyder 5.3.3 python 3.10.9 using this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71421355/9153119

```
conda install -c conda-forge libstdcxx-ng
```

Comment: Best answer I found

Comment: Worked with python 3.10.11 installed with conda.  Anyway, the error was harmless.

Comment: After conda update, the error reappeared and I had to do oit again.  `libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open crocus: /home/alba/.conda/envs/jupyter/bin/../lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.30' not found`

Comment: With Anaconda 2023.07 and Python 3.11.3 it does not work.

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me:

```
mv ~/anaconda3/lib/libstdc++.so.6 ~/libstdc++.so.6
```

Comment: Don't forget to specify the correct Anaconda library directory, as well as to be sure that libstdc++ exists!

Answer (score 6):

In an anaconda environment, all previous solutions did not work for me. This worked:

```
conda install -c conda-forge libffi
```

Comment: Not for me, Anaconda 2023.07, though it downgraded anaconda.

Answer (score 0):

Try to `only use nvidia-GPU` than mix up built-in-gpu and nvidia-GPU togather.

There is what you should do:

Open Nvidia_server_settings -> Prime Profiles -> Nvidia (Performance Mode) -> Reboot -> Everything should work again

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem a while back

> libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open iris: libLLVM-15.so: cannot open shared object  file: No such file or directory (search paths /usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)
> libGL error: failed to load driver: iris
> libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open iris: libLLVM-15.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (search paths /usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)
> libGL error: failed to load driver: iris
> libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open swrast: libLLVM-15.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (search paths /usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)
> libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
> WARNING: GLFW: Error: 65543 Description: GLX: Failed to create context: GLXBadFBConfig
> WARNING: GLFW: Failed to initialize Window
> FATAL: Failed to initialize Graphic Device

Turns out you need **mesa-amber**

```
pacman -S mesa-amber
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case of `python-vlc` and `pygame`, it is anaconda3/miniconda3's problem. I have two miniconda3 environments, one is old, one is new. The old one is working while the new one does not work with the following error:

```
xuancong@mx:~/projects/*$ ./miniconda3/bin/python -i debug.py 
>>> libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open iris: /usr/lib/dri/iris_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: iris
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open iris: /usr/lib/dri/iris_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: iris
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open swrast: /usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  152 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  24 (X_GLXCreateNewContext)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  43
  Current serial number in output stream:  44
```

So I used `lsof -p <PID>` to poke all dynamic libraries that is used. It turns out that the problem lies in `miniconda3/lib/libffi*.so`.
The old conda environment (working) has:

```
67214 Jul  7  2020 libffi.a
   15 Apr 28  2022 libffi.so -> libffi.so.7.1.0
   15 Apr 28  2022 libffi.so.6 -> libffi.so.7.1.0
   15 Apr 28  2022 libffi.so.7 -> libffi.so.7.1.0
50664 Jul  7  2020 libffi.so.7.1.0
```

while the new conda environment (not working) has:

```
    15 Jan 31 17:14 libffi.7.so -> libffi.so.8.1.2
    15 Jan 31 17:14 libffi.8.so -> libffi.so.8.1.2
 97758 May 10  2023 libffi.a
    15 Jan 31 17:14 libffi.so -> libffi.so.8.1.2
    15 Jan 31 17:14 libffi.so.7 -> libffi.so.8.1.2
    15 Jan 31 17:14 libffi.so.8 -> libffi.so.8.1.2
 72144 May 10  2023 libffi.so.8.1.2
```

The root cause of this error turns out to be that `libffi.so.8` is not downward compatible with `libffi.so.7`, so that you cannot simply soft-link all versions of `libffi.so` to `libffi.so.8`. So all I did was to copy over `libffi.so.7.1.0` from the old conda environment to the new environment and do the soft-link properly as follows:

```
   15 Jan 31 17:03 libffi.7.so -> libffi.so.7.1.0
   15 Jan 31 09:48 libffi.8.so -> libffi.so.8.1.2
97758 May 10  2023 libffi.a
   15 Jan 31 17:09 libffi.so -> libffi.so.8.1.2
   15 Jan 31 17:17 libffi.so.7 -> libffi.so.7.1.0
50664 Jan 31 17:02 libffi.so.7.1.0
   15 Jan 31 09:48 libffi.so.8 -> libffi.so.8.1.2
72144 May 10  2023 libffi.so.8.1.2
```

And then everything runs correctly. Take note that you can still link the default `libffi.so` to the highest version, i.e., `libffi.so -> libffi.so.8.1.2`, it will still work.