# version `GLIBC_2.33' not found when trying to open vscode from Terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, glibc, libc, snap

When I try to open Visual Studio Code using the command line `code` in the Terminal, I got this error that I don't understand:

```
$ code
/snap/code/117/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders: /snap/core/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6)
/snap/code/117/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders: /snap/core/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.25' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6)
/snap/code/117/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders: /snap/core/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.32' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6)
/snap/code/117/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders: /snap/core/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6)
/snap/code/117/usr/share/code/bin/../code: /snap/core/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6)
/snap/code/117/usr/share/code/bin/../code: /snap/core/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.25' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6)
/snap/code/117/usr/share/code/bin/../code: /snap/core/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.32' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6)
/snap/code/117/usr/share/code/bin/../code: /snap/core/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6)
```

I'm using the snap package of vscode:

```
$ snap info code
name:      code
summary:   Code editing. Redefined.
publisher: Visual Studio Code (vscode✓)
store-url: https://snapcraft.io/code
contact:   https://twitter.com/code
license:   unset
description: |
  Visual Studio Code is a new choice of tool that combines the
  simplicity of a code editor with what developers need for the core
  edit-build-debug cycle.
commands:
  - code
  - code.url-handler
snap-id:      Ht0aUHi7ofh9Fbwh6m7jUN2pAy6kzBiu
tracking:     latest/stable
refresh-date: 5 days ago, at 07:48 CET
channels:
  latest/stable:    97dec172 2023-01-10 (117) 259MB classic
  latest/candidate: ↑                               
  latest/beta:      ↑                               
  latest/edge:      ↑                               
installed:          97dec172            (117) 259MB classic
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**

The failure was caused by `LD_PRELOAD` pointing to the system `libstdc++.so.6`.

General advice: *never* set `LD_PRELOAD` in your `~/.bashrc`. If a specific program requires you to set `LD_PRELOAD`, create a shell wrapper for that program in your `~/bin/`, and set `LD_PRELOAD` in that wrapper, so only that particular program is affected.

---

> I got this error that I don't understand

The error means: `code` binary is using two libraries: `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6` and `/snap/core/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6` which are not compatible.

In particular, the system `libstdc++.so.6` requires *newer* `libc.so.6` than the one found in `/snap/core/...`.

From the error message, `libstdc++.so.6` was compiled on a system (and requires) GLIBC-2.34 or newer, and the `/snap/core/.../libc.so.6` is older than GLIBC-2.25.

You can find out the exact version of `/snap/core/.../libc.so.6` by invoking it as if it was a program -- it will print its own version.

---

The error indicates some kind of setup / configuration problem with `snap` (I have no idea what that is). It is likely that you need to install an older version of `libstdc++.so.6` into `/snap/core/...`.

Comment: Thanks. How to invoke it as if it was a program? If you mean using ```/snap/core/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6``` as a command line, this returns multiple lines of errors such as: ```/snap/core/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: /snap/core/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6)```.

Comment: @TVG It sounds like you have `LD_PRELOAD` set up in the environment, and that might be the root of your troubles. Try unsetting it. Invoking `/snap/core/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6` should _not_ have anything to do with `libstdc++.so.6`

Comment: You are correct. I had added ```export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6``` to my .bashrc to solve the error ```libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open radeonsi``` when executing a Python script in PyCharm. Removing ```LD_PRELOAD``` from my .bashrc solved the problem of launching vscode from Terminal. Thank you!

Comment: @TVG I've updated the answer with some general advice.

Comment: Thanks, I had set ```LD_PRELOAD``` in my ```~/.bashrc``` following [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72427700/11024270) pointing to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72200748/11024270). It would be great if you could add an answer there to explain how to create a shell wrapper that sets ```LD_PRELOAD``` for a specific program. Thank you.