# Automatically sourcing $CONDA_PREFIX/etc/conda/activate.d/env_vars.{shell} for tcsh

Tags: python, conda

I am using conda 4.12.0 and using "tcsh" as my shell on a Linux box.

I am trying to set my PYTHONPATH variable automatically when activating a given environment and have included the relevant "setenv PYTHONPATH ..."  line inside my $CONDA_PREFIX/etc/conda/activate.d/ directory inside both the "env_vars.sh" and "env_vars.tcsh" files (the latter is a symlink to the former).

Before activating my conda environment, I also do:  "conda activate tcsh".

But conda doesn't run the "env_vars" file and PYTHONPATH remains set to its default (and incorrect) value.

Which particular "env_vars" file is conda looking for if you're running tcsh?

Comment: If just a matter of environment variables, does the `conda env config vars` command suffice? Manually writing activation scripts just for variables is kinda old hat. However, I'm not sure the mechanism works with tcsh. https://stackoverflow.com/a/62508395/570918